# Set CountVectorizer result to pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-mining, countvectorizer

I need to set pandas.DataFrame with matrix features produced by CountVectorizer.

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
count_vect.fit(text)

xtrain_count = count_vect.transform(train_x)
SaveTxt = pandas.DataFrame()
SaveTxt['text']=xtrain_count
```

but in the last line `SaveTxt['text']=xtrain_count` I got following errors!

```
 raise ValueError('Cannot set a frame with no defined index '
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

I was wondering how should I set result matrix of CountVectorizer to dataframe?
CountVectorizer result is a csr_matrix with about 20000 rows and 200000 columns and contents are integer (1 to 6)

Comment: can you share a small example of the contents of `xtrain_count`?

Comment: It's a matrix with about 20000 rows and 200000 columns and contents are integer (1 to 6)

Comment: it's a numpy array?

Comment: it's csr_matrix

Comment: you're trying to save a (massive) matrix into a new column of an empty dataframe?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: well, it makes very little sense to do that, but if you really want to, my suggestion is to try `SaveTxt.loc[0,'text'] = xtrain_count`

Comment: I tried but got this error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score -1):

```py
pd.DataFrame(my_csr_matrix.todense())
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
import random

import lorem
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

m = 10
random.seed(0)
data = [lorem.paragraph() for _ in range(m)]

cv = CountVectorizer()
cv.fit(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=cv.transform(data).todense())

print(df.shape)
print(df.head())
```

**Result:**

```
(10, 27)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
0  1  2  2  3  3  0  2  0  3  1   2   2   2   1   1   5   3   2   1   3   1   0   2   2   1   4   4
1  0  0  4  1  0  0  1  3  0  3   2   0   1   0   1   1   1   5   3   2   0   0   1   0   0   3   1
2  0  2  3  1  1  1  2  0  2  0   1   1   1   1   1   3   2   0   1   2   1   4   3   0   1   2   5
3  3  3  4  7  1  2  4  2  2  0   1   2   1   1   0   0   0   2   1   3   2   2   2   2   0   3   4
4  2  3  1  2  3  4  1  1  4  3   2   4   2   2   3   3   2   0   2   3   2   5   4   3   2   1   2
```

Comment: And yes, I am aware of the consequences of putting data of this scale into a DataFrame, but scale/efficiency was not the topic of @Sina's question. Are we getting XY'd here? Maybe.